# Mutt new e-mail notifications in tmux window

Tags: email, tmux, mutt, imap

I am on `tmux`, with `mutt` in an inactive window. If IMAP flags change on a message through external means, I see the visual bell and the status bar changes, drawing my attention to the e-mail client. That works well.

What I would like to do but still can't get to work is:

- Get a proper notification about incoming e-mail whilst in another tmux window
- Never get notifications later than 5 minutes from their arrival, possibly fine-tuning this interval

I use Gmail over IMAPS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could call a small script from your tmux status bar that updates with any new mail:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set maildirs
maildirs="$HOME/Mail/*/INBOX/new/"

find $maildirs -type f | wc -l
```

And in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg=yellow,bright]Mail: #(tmuxmail) ..."
```

This count will be updated according to the status-interval value, eg.,:
`set -g status-interval 1`

Comment: I am accepting even if this is for local mail, not for Gmail over IMAPS...

Answer (score 1):

You may look at [tmux-powerline](https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline)
If you don't like to solarize your tmux colorscheme as I do, you may look at [mailcheck](http://packages.debian.org/sid/mailcheck) that tmux-powerline use to check email.